# Serialize SendGridMessage object

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, json.net, sendgrid

I am building a system that need to send some transactional mails, and to achieve this I am using Azure storage queues to store the message temporarily before it is picked up by a WebJob and sent off to the intended recipient.

My Code is as follows:

```
SendGridMessage message = new SendGridMessage();
//Populate message with details - omitted for brevity

var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var modelAsString = serializer.Serialize(message);

try
{
    var setting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("AzureStorageConnectionString");
    var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(setting);
    var queueClient = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
    var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("FSPortalEmailQueue");
    queue.CreateIfNotExists();

    queue.AddMessage(new CloudQueueMessage(modelAsString));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Something went wrong
}
```

Each time I try to execute the coder, an exception is thrown on the

> var modelAsString = serializer.Serialize(message);
>
> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

The inner exception thrown was

> {"Bad key path!"} from source "SendGrid.SmtpApi"

Please advise what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more digging, it turns out that the message.header node was not being initialised. After adding

```
message.Header = new SendGrid.SmtpApi.Header();

message.Header.SetTo(new List<String> { enquiry.EnquiryCreatedBy.Email });
```

all started working pretty magically

Comment: Even though I managed to successfully serialize the object, on the receiving end (Azure webjob triggered by a queueItem) the deserialization fails on the MailAddress.